# Passing EnvironmentVariables from AWS Codepipeline to CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am having trouble passing EnvironmentVariables from AWS Codepipeline to CodeBuild. The only documentation I can find on this topic is [this AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodeBuild.html) which gives a basic example but as you see below, I require an imported sub value. All attempts give me the error: `Value of property Configuration must be an object with String (or simple type) properties`.

```
  - Name: EmptyHostingBucket
    Actions:
      - Name: EmptyHostingBucket
        RunOrder: 5
        ActionTypeId:
          Category: Build
          Owner: AWS
          Provider: CodeBuild
          Version: 1
        Configuration:
          ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuildEmptyBucket
          EnvironmentVariables:
            - Name: HOSTING_BUCKET
              Value:
                Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${ProjectName}-website-hosting-bucket"
        InputArtifacts:
          - Name: SourceArtifacts
        OutputArtifacts:
          - Name: BuildEmptyBucket
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably because:

> The value for the EnvironmentVariables parameter takes the form of a **JSON array** of environment variable objects.

Thus it should be as **string**, as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodeBuild.html#action-reference-CodeBuild-example):

```
EnvironmentVariables:
    !Sub
      - '[{"name":"HOSTING_BUCKET","value":"${BucketName}","type":"PLAINTEXT"}]'
      - BucketName: 
          Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${ProjectName}-website-hosting-bucket"
```

The above is example. Probably some adjustments still need to be made.